# Looping through model list in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to loop through a list that is declared in my model. I want to loop through this list in my JavaScript but I get an error saying the name 'i' does not exist in the current context.
Here is my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  $("#tablelist").html('<tr><td>@Model.myuserList.ElementAt(i).user_name</td></tr>');
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use a clientside variable on the serverside, which is a bit too early.

Comment: also why are you changing the contents of the #tablelist (assuming its a table) 10 times. Do you mean to use append() instead of html()?

Comment: @adeneo he is using this code in javascript not in server side right?

Comment: @ PseudoNinja Yeah I meant append

Comment: I am new to javascript, I just want to populate the table dynamically

Comment: If I can suggest something is for you to find a way to convert this model into a string that will be understood by a JavaScript as an object with all the model data so you can use it in JavaScript. I did that quite a few times with PHP so it is confirmed to work perfectly.

Comment: @SivaRajini - I'm guessing `@Model.myuserList.ElementAt(i).user_name` outputs something from MVC, and that usually happens long before the page is sent to the client.

Comment: @user2835306: side note on performance issues with large HTML manipulations in a loop. If `$("#tablelist")` is an element currently in the DOM do not append to it in a loop as you will start seeing performance issues rather quickly even at only 10 loops. Either, `$("#tablelist").detach()` first then re-attach or use a in-memory variable to append to first then assign the html result to it. i.e: `var $memoryObject = $('<table></table>'); ... $memoryObject.append(...); .... $(#tablelist).html($memoryObject.html())`  or similar